# Why won't Babel transform my class properties?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have the following `person.js`

```js
export class Person {
    firstName = ""
    lastName = ""
    middleName = "Nothing"

    constructor(first, last){
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
    }

    get fullName() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.middleName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run Webpack, I get a syntax error pointing to the first equal sign between `firstName` and the double quotes.

If I remove all the properties before the constructor, everything works fine (although I have to include a definition for `middleName` in the constructor).

I don't know if this is a webpack issue or if this is a Babel issue.  If I enter that code into Babel's online **Test it out** compiler, Babel doesn't seem to have an issue with it.

I have tried configuring Babel using `babel-preset-es2015`, `babel-preset-es2016` and `babel-preset-env` and nothing changed.

Any idea why that is giving me an error?  Are property definitions like that only available in TypeScript?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use the plugin [`transform-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) or the [`stage-2`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/) preset which includes this plugin. Without this you won't be able to transform class properties:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

Or:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-2
```

Then make sure to include it in your `.babelrc` or other means of configuration:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Or:

```
{
  "presets:" [
    "stage-2"
  ]
}
```

Comment: do I still need the babel-preset-env preset if I use the state-2 preset?  I was using env because that was what was shown in the documentation I was reading -- don't really understand what the preset is doing.

Comment: So, using stage-2 corrected the error I was having but then gave me a new error during the minify process.  However, using the plugin solved everything!  Thanks so much.

Comment: Do we need this plugin because this is not a Javascript feature? I have a variable that I want to be initialised only once and I also want to access it on a static way. How would I achieve that without installing plugins?

Answer (score 0):

you might be missing `"parser":"babel-eslint",` in eslintrc.json file. This will ensure babel parser is used.