# Unexpected token '=' in JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am currently dumbfounded why I am receiving unexpected token '=' error on the equals to the right of `auth`. If I put it in the constructor, that specific error goes away and I get the same error on `checkAuth`. The most troubling part of this all is that it is working perfectly fine in another of my codebases. The error only occurs after I have moved it. I have tried restarting webpack, removing the code and typing it by hand, recreating the file. Nothing is working and I am lost.

```
class AuthenticationCheck extends Component {

    auth = new AuthService();
         ^ `Unexpected token`
    checkAuth = () => {
      if (!this.auth.loggedIn()) {
        if (reload) {
          this.props.history.push('/login');
        }
      }

      return <ComposedClass auth={this.auth} />;
    };
```

My `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-env", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "react-css-modules",
      {
        "filetypes": {
          ".scss": {
            "syntax": "postcss-scss"
          }
        },
        "webpackHotModuleReloading": true
      }
    ],
    ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": true }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need `babel-preset-stage-2` as well  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43903670/1516309

Comment: @jakeforaker That did it. God bless.